# Using Android CalendarContract.Calendars to get user-created calendars under ICS

Tags: android, calendar, android-contentresolver

I have an old app written prior to Android API 14 which used to access all my Google calendars just fine.  I upgraded to ICS a few months ago and incorporated the changes to use the API and everything still worked fine.  But a recent ROM flash caused it to break again.

The problem is the application is not able to see any calendars except for the default Google Calender.  Previously calling the calendar content resolver would return all calendars, including the holiday calendar.

I can't find anything in the API documents which gives a hint what I might need to do here.

```
public static List<dateEvent> readCalendar(Context context, String idString ) {
  ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
  final Uri calendar_URI = Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
  final Uri dates_URI = Instances.CONTENT_URI;

  String selection = "((" + Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME + " = ?) AND ("
    + Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = ?) AND ("
    + Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT + " = ?))";

  String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                "myaddress@gmail.com", "com.google", "myaddress@gmail.com"};
  cursor = contentResolver.query(calendar_URI,
            (new String[] {   Calendars._ID,
                              Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME,
                              Calendars.VISIBLE  } ),
            selection, selectionArgs, null );

  List<dateEvent> dateList = new LinkedList<dateEvent>();

  while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    final String _id = cursor.getString(0);
    final String displayName = cursor.getString(1);
    System.out.println("Id: " + _id + " Display Name: " + displayName);
  }
}
```

Comment: Included in original message.

Comment: I didn't find a solution for the above problem, but found a way around it.  I was able to accomplish the same thing using CalendarContract.Instances; this let me build a query that returned only entries which matched the CalendarContract.Instances.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME I wanted.